# Batch Script to Multiple Excel Files (1 variable)

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, call

I want to create a batch script that will take a .csv file that is tagged with a time stamp in the name open it, then open a specific macro-enabled Excel file (which will always be the same) and then run the macro in the 2nd workbook effective for the first workbook only.

So example:

BATCH:

```bat
for %%f in (PATH\*.csv) do ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%%f")
```

I have this line to account for the changing time stamp

then the batch continues:

```bat
call PATH\Macro.xlsm
```

1. The CMD seems to stall after the first part and will not call the second file.
2. If I can have this open both files, can the macro run for all open workbooks rather than just the one it's built in via batch?

Any help would be appreciated as I am very new to this.

Comment: `Call`, _had you read the help information in the Command Prompt, i.e. `call /?`_, calls one batch program from another. `PATH\Macro.xlsm` is not a batch program, and therefore does not require the `Call` command!

Comment: Does it need to be a batch file which does that? I think it would be easier to have the logic to handle the csv files in the `Macro.xlsm`. So you just need to launch that file, it then pics the csv files and proceeds them. So you only have to deal with VBA and not the batch script additionally. Keep it simple. • Alternatively use a VBScript instead of batch. VBScript is close to VBA so maybe easier to handle than batch. Using batch just looks over complicating things to me.